# blank page - JSON to HTML table

Tags: javascript, html, json

How i can display json in table html ?

This is my code and it's not working, i see a blank page

```
<script>
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "http://37.247.116.189:88/stalker_portal/api/users";

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        myFunction(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();

function myFunction(response) {
    var arr = JSON.parse(response);
    var i;
    var out = "<table>";

    for(i = 0; i < arr.results; i++) {
        out += "<tr><td>" + 
        arr[i].login +
        "</td><td>" +
        arr[i].full_name +
        "</td><td>" +
        arr[i].phone +
        "</td></tr>";
    }
    out += "</table>";
    document.getElementById("mydata").innerHTML = out;
}
</script>
```

but its not working, i don't know where is the problem ?

Comment: What's the problem? You need to do some basic debugging. Use the developer tools in your browser. Look at the Network tab. Does the request get made? Does the response match your expectations? Look at the Console. Are there any errors? Add some `console.log()` statements to the code. Does `onreadystatechange` fire? Do the `if` statement conditions ever pass? What is the value of `responseText`? Does `myFunction` ever fire? Does `JSON.parse` return the expected value? Does `out` end up with the expected value?

Comment: Well, are you getting an error?  Have you debugged your code to see everything operating as expected?

Comment: We need more info.  For example, is there a javascript error in the console?  Can you print the data from the response before trying to render the table?

Answer (score 0):

I just did this part, its working fine, where its printing the data:

```html
<html>
    <head>
     <script >
    window.onload = function() {
        //var arr = JSON.parse(response);
        var arr2 = [
        {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"},
        {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},
        {"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones"}
     ]
        var i;
        var out = "<table>";
    
        for(i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
            out += "<tr><td>" + 
            arr2[i].firstName +
            "</td><td>" +
            arr2[i].lastName +
            "</td><td></tr>"
        }
        out += "</table>";
        document.getElementById("mydata").innerHTML = out;
    }
    </script>
    
     </head>
    <body>
    
    <div id='mydata'>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

The rest would be check if you are http calls are being made properly, if you have access to it. Check your developer console, right click --> inpect.
First of all make sure you are getting the JSON file properly, then use this code,